# Matplotlib strptime with day rollover

Tags: python, matplotlib, strptime

I have a timestamp that is in H:M:S and is being handled via strptime to create an array of times. My problem arises when I go from 23:59:59 to 0:0:0. When I go to graph this the line jumps all the way back on the graph. Is there a way that I can handle this without knowing the day? I.e. I am only given H:M:S no day and I am trying not to iterate through the entire array to find this situation.

Comment: you mean you just jump to another day and it must increase value of time not returning back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase a day parameter over a loop:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
dayn = 0
while True:
    t = raw_input()
    h,m,s = t[:1],t[3:5],t[6:]
    t_strc = time.strptime(str(dayn)+':'+t,'%d:%H:%M:%S')
    if int(h+m+s)>235958:
        dayn += 1
    r = time2num(t_strc) # a function read tm_mday and other values to give increasing number
    plt.plot(x,r) # x is your data , r is time
plt.show()
```

where time2num is a function that turn time structure (with days) into a number value